# End method with indirect throw

Tags: c#, exception

recently I was running about a problem where I did throw an Exception, but it was not consumed by the GUI-Thread. I found a solution for this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358791/throw-exception-on-ui-thread).

As there are several places where I would need it, I want to place it in a method.
Now I am struggling in Methods which except to have a return value which cannot be null.

```
enum SomeEnum
{
    ONE,
    TWO

}

private SomeEnum DoSomeExecption()
{
    var e = new NotImplementedException();
    ThrowException(e);
    //return null;

}

internal static void ThrowException(Exception e)
{
    var dispatcher = App.Current.Dispatcher;

    if (dispatcher != null)
    {
        if (!dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                throw e;
            }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        }
        else
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to tell the calling method that execution will stop with the method call?

Comment: Injecting an exception into the UI thread is not a workaround.  There's nobody there to catch it, so the app will terminate.  Might as well call Environment.Exit().

Comment: There is a `DoesNotReturn` attribute but I believe that's only used for static analysis of nullability. And would require a method that does in fact never return (unlike yours which will if `dispatcher` happens to be null or if it does manage to invoke on the Dispatcher).

Comment: Thanks for the worries, Hans Passant, but I do catch all the unhandled exception inside the GUI thread, to prevent a closing of the application without any information to the user.